# Accessing TemplateRef gives an empty comment node in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

Building a custom sorting component in Angular2, but I'm having trouble accessing a template variable. I need to be able to access the `ng-template` so that I can "clone/stamp" then element to create drop zones, based on the template provided.

I've tried using `@ViewChild("dropzone")`, but it also returns an empty comment node.

Here's the Component

```
@Component({
    selector: "my-sortable",
    template: `
        <ng-content select="my-sortable-content"></ng-content>
    `
})
export class SortableComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    @Input() //@ContentChild("dropzone")
    dzTemplate: any;

    onAfterViewInit() {
        // Outputs an object but the 
        // nativeElement is an empty 
        // comment node
        console.log(this.dzTemplate); 
    }
}
```

And here's the HTML

```
<my-sortable [dzTemplate]="dropzone">
    <ng-template #dropzone>
        <p>Hey, I'm a drop zone!!</p>
    </ng-template>
    <my-sortable-content>
        <div *ngFor="...">
            ...
        </div>
    </my-sortable-content>
</my-sortable>
```

[image]

Comment: There is no `ng-template` element after angular compilation. You can read `ViewContainer` from this template reference variable and then add components to this container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. Turns out that the `ElementRef` object has the method `createEmbeddedView()` which will return a `EmbeddedViewRef`. From there, I can access the DOM elements in the rootNodes property. These nodes are not attached to any element yet, so they're perfect for cloning/stamping.

Comment: Did you mean [`TemplateRef` has `createEmbeddedView()`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createEmbeddedView)? I don't _think_ [`ElementRef` should have it](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef).

Comment: Yes the `TemplateRef` and `ViewContainerRef` both have `createEmbeddedView()`

Answer (score 0):

I've needed to do something similar and ended up needing to use [forwardRef](https://angular.io/api/core/forwardRef) from angular core

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';

/* ... in component somewhere */
  @ViewChild(forwardRef(() => SomeComponent)) // You can use a DI token I believe
  private paginationControls: SomeComponent;
```

It might be tricky with the any type though, give it a shot! :D You may need to use [injection tokens](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injectiontoken) too - but I'm not sure...

If you need to change behavior based on the type of the template, you would be much better off with some static typing and switching over a dynamic string or something. I've built a map of componentID -> component types before and used that to instantiate new components with `ComponentFactoryResolver` - it's a bit of a pain since you need to list out all the cases, but if you need to drop down into details of the component in your sorter component, then you'll have to do this (if the forwardRef ends up not working).